# pythonで unittest？@classmethod？があります。

Tags: python

https://github.com/wylee/Dijkstar/blob/master/dijkstar/tests/test_graph.py
cls.graphのデータの実行方法を教えて下さい。
実行しましたが、何も表示されません。
できれば、full scriptだと助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これはテスト用ファイルで実行例ではないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`test_graph.py`は、ユニットテストモジュールですが、実行するコードがないので`python test_graph.py`では何も実行しません。それで、コマンドラインからテストを起動します。例えば、次のようなコマンドでテストが可能です。

```
python -m unittest tests/test_graph.py
```

・参考　公式ドキュメント unittest [26.4.2. コマンドラインインターフェイス](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)

また、`@classmethod`が使われていますが、この質問でははあまり重要な話ではないと思うので、取り敢えずは`setUpClass()`はテストが実行される前に呼び出されるメソッドで、`tearDownClass()`はテストが実行された後に呼び出されるメソッドで、`unittest`側の事情でクラスメソッドにしていると思っておけばいいのではないでしょうか。